# reaсt-grid-layout - не получается создать новый элемент

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

Я делаю проект на React, в котором я использую react-grid-layout. Я могу создать несколько grid-сеток по нажатию на кнопку в файле App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Grid from "./Grid";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  const [wrappersArray, setWrappersArray] = useState([]);
  const [idCounter, setIdCounter] = useState(0);
  const [elemsList, setElemsList] = useState({   // мой layout
    0: [
      { i: "b", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
      { i: "k", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 }
    ],
    1: [
      { i: "b", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
      { i: "k", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 }
    ],
    2: [
      { i: "b", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
      { i: "k", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 }
    ]
  });

  console.log("elems list", elemsList);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid #000", padding: "20px" }}>
        <Grid
          layout={elemsList[idCounter]}
          setElemsList={setElemsList}
          idCounter={idCounter}
        />
        <Button setElemsList={setElemsList} idCounter={idCounter} />
      </div>

      {wrappersArray}

      <button   // btn to create new grid
        style={{ margin: "20px 0 0 0" }}
        onClick={() => {
          setWrappersArray(
            wrappersArray.concat(  // создаю новые сетки с уникальными id (idCounter и есть ID)
              <div
                style={{ border: "1px solid #000", padding: "20px" }}
                key={idCounter}
              >
                <Grid
                  layout={elemsList[idCounter]}
                  setElemsList={setElemsList}
                  idCounter={idCounter}
                />
                <Button setElemsList={setElemsList} idCounter={idCounter} />
              </div>
            )
          );
          setIdCounter(idCounter + 1);  // инкрементируем ID чтобы сделать его уникальным (ID также совпадает с индексом layout)
        }}
      >
        add grid
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

В компоненте Grid я сохраняю изменения своих layout, используя обработчик onDragStop и onLayoutChange:

```
import "./styles.css";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";
import React from "react";
import "react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";

export default function CustomLayout({
  layout,
  onDragStart,
  setElemsList,
  idCounter
}) {
  return (
    <GridLayout
      className="layout"
      onDragStart={onDragStart}
      onDragStop={(newLayout) => {
        setElemsList((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          [idCounter]: newLayout
        }));
      }}
      onLayoutChange={(newLayout) => {
        setElemsList((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          [idCounter]: newLayout
        }));
      }}
      layout={layout}
      cols={24}
      rowHeight={80}
      width={1600}
    >
      {layout.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.i} style={{ background: "purple", color: "#fff" }}>
            {item.i}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </GridLayout>
  );
}
```

Наконец, в компоненте Button я просто добавляю новый элемент в определенную сетку:

```
export default function Button({ setElemsList, idCounter }) {
  const newItem = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    i: "test" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setElemsList((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          [idCounter]: [...prevState[idCounter], newItem]  // add to certain grid
        }));
      }}
    >
      Add elem
    </button>
  );
}
```

Сама проблема: если я создам новый Grid, а затем попытаюсь добавить новый элемент в один из более старых Grid, то это не сработает. Что я мог сделать не так? 
P.S. ссылка на исходный код: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cori-qxvpkx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Судя по примерам, `idCounter` у тебя увеличился при добавлении "сетки", а все добавление элементов у тебя идет от "текущего" значения `idCounter`...

Comment: @ksa если я ваш комментарий понял правильно, то вы мне говорите, что у всех сеток одинаковый параметр idCounter. В таком случае, это не так, я проверял это через консоль

Comment: У сеток разные ключи в объекте... А вот значение `idCounter` просто увеличивается при добавлении сетки и потом никак не меняется. Т.е. у тебя в примерах нет "переключения" между сетками...

Comment: @ksa оно передается в компонент и там более не меняется, то есть ключи совпадают и переключение есть

Answer (score 0):

Что ж, пользователь [@ksa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520359/ksa) оказался прав, я неправильно реализовал переключение сеток. Оставлю рабочее решение на случай, если кому-то оно понадобится: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cori-qxvpkx?file=/src/App.js